# RabbitMQ AWS autoscaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ and I am evaluating it for my next project.  Is it possible to use AWS autoscaling with RabbitMQ?  How would the multiple instances coordinate messages across multiple instance queues? I see that RabbitMQ has clustering capabilities but appears not to fit in an autoscaling model.  I did find this post,

[How to set up autoscaling RabbitMQ Cluster AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340413/how-to-set-up-autoscaling-rabbitmq-cluster-aws)

It fixed the scale-up issues but did not address what to do when the instances scale-down.  The issue with scaling-down is the potential for messages still in the queues when the instance is removed.  Clustering is ok but would like to leverage autoscaling whenever possible.

Comment: I don't see that working out very well. It seems like you are trying to fit RabbitMQ into a role that it wasn't designed to fill. Have you looked at queue services that were designed to scale on demand, like SQS and IronMQ?

Comment: Yes, I looked at SQS.  SQS certainly fits my needs and definitely leverages AWS scaling model.  However, I would like to use a platform agnostic solution for future platform flexibility.  I will check out IronMQ.  If I do go with RabbitMQ how do people handle rapid scaling?  I have a REST based SaaS IoT warehouse inventory management application.  Our expectations is that the queueing requests will grow rather quickly.  Like I said, I am ok with setting up RabbitMQ as a cluster and just manage the queue request growth manually.  However, maybe not for AWS scaling.

Comment: Hello Mark, just cleaning up my Stackoverflow unanswered questions.  Can you respond back with an answer so I can give you credit?  You did answer my question so you should get credit.